# Create a swift2 class from classname

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, init, classname

I'm new in Swift.

In objective C, I pushed custom UIViewController create from its classname:

```
NSString *classString = "customViewController";
UIViewController *vc = [[NSClassFromString(classString) alloc] init];
[self pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

I cannot build class in swift, this doesn't work:

```
let myClass = NSClassFromString("customViewController") as! UIViewController.Type
let vc = myClass.init()
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

> Error : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it fails is that the view controller class name you have referenced (`customViewController`) is not fully qualified by the **module name**. This can be found in Interface Builder below the custom class name:

[image]

You should change the class name string to represent the fully qualified name of the view controller, for example:

```
let myClass = NSClassFromString("MyProject.customViewController") as! UIViewController.Type
```

Comment: Module name is better to determine by `NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String`

Comment: Thank you!!!! The string has to be prefix by the project Name "MyProject.customViewController"

Comment: Much better would be to merely insist on a non-module-specific name using the `@objc` tag to name the class, no? Something like `@objc(CustomViewController)`...

Answer (score 6):

`NSClassFromString` uses the fully qualified class name.

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController { }

let className = NSStringFromClass(CustomViewController.self)
// let className = "MyAppName.CustomViewController" // Equivalent
let aClass = NSClassFromString(className) as! UIViewController.Type
let viewController = aClass.init()
```

Alternatively you override the fully qualified class name with the `@objc` attribute:

```
@objc(CustomViewController)
class CustomViewController: UIViewController { }

let className = NSStringFromClass(CustomViewController.self)
// let className = "CustomViewController" // Equivalent
let aClass = NSClassFromString(className) as! UIViewController.Type
let viewController = aClass.init()
```

Either way, `NSStringFromClass` will always return the valid class name for `NSClassFromString` method.

Comment: Without `@objc` annotation it does not work in playground.

Comment: @SteveWilford `NSClassFromString` uses the name specified in `@objc` attribute. This code also works in application

Comment: @SteveWilford added sample using fully qualified names

Comment: This does not work, the app crash with the same fatal error. And I have to get the Class Name from a String, unlike your 2 other exemple, sorry...

Comment: @DamienRomito Double checked in Swift 2 with XCode 7 and both samples work as expected. I've edited the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: If your project name has any spaces, then all words needed to be connected via a under scored "_".   Indeed, NSStringFromClass will tell you the exact fully qualified name.  Good job!

Answer (score 6):

I created a very simple extension to do this more quickly
https://github.com/damienromito/NSObject-FromClassName

```
extension NSObject {
    class func fromClassName(className : String) -> NSObject {
        let className = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"] as! String + "." + className
        let aClass = NSClassFromString(className) as! UIViewController.Type
        return aClass.init()
    }
}
```

---

In my case, i do this to load the ViewController I want:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let controllers = ["SettingsViewController", "ProfileViewController", "PlayerViewController"]
    self.presentController(controllers.firstObject as! String)

}

func presentController(controllerName : String){
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: NSObject.fromClassName(controllerName) as! UIViewController )
    nav.navigationBar.translucent = false
    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Best of all solutions

Comment: Works like a charm